# Can you get millisecond precise multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, audio, rust, real-time

So, I'm planning a project for a real-time audio in Rust. There are portions that can be processed in parallel, however I need latency of no more than 1-2ms, consistently. Is there any way to make use of multiple cores in this type of project?

Comment: 1-2ms is orders of magnitude longer than typical inter-thread signaling latency and so I'm guessing that you may be able to thread off some of the processing if required.  It all kinda depends on code/data design and overall loading.

Comment: Anything that works for this in C/C++ should be able to work in Rust, so investigating techniques there may be a productive route forward.

Comment: I've seen successful low latency, real-time audio projects in rust. 1-2 ms is very small, but if you're very careful you should be able to get something working that is below the threshold of noticeable lag.